# Non greedy match replacement with gensub and awk

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

I am trying to clean a bunch of sentences with POS tags using AWK. Each sentence can have none, one or multiple tags with format `\POS{word|type}`. I am having a hard time with sentences with multiple tags. I cannot find a way to make the regex non-greedy. Example

Input

```
sentence_1,My \POS{tailor,noun} is \POS{rich,adj}.
```

Desired output

```
sentence_1,My tailor is rich.
```

Where I am currently

```
echo "sentence_1,My \POS{tailor,noun} is \POS{rich,adj}."|awk -F "," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {_id=$1;$1="";s=gensub(/\\POS{(.+?),.+?}/, "\\1", "gm", $0); print _id s}'
```

The wrong output I get:

```
sentence_1,My tailor,noun} is \POS{rich.
```

The sentence regex is not greedy. I know awk cannot handle greedy expressions, but how would you do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the expression is greedy despite I added the question marks. First group is from \POS{ to the last comma of the second POS tag

Comment: You could match `[^}]+}`.

Comment: OP has question about regex and regex tag was there in base question, not sure why it was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or a bit "simpler" (?) with gawk's `gensub` (as originally tried):

```sh
$ echo 'sentence_1,My \POS{tailor,noun} is \POS{rich,adj}' | gawk '{s=gensub(/\\POS{([^,]+),[^}]+}/, "\\1", "G", $0); print s}'
sentence_1,My tailor is rich
```

Comment: I like this one, could you explain what's the change? apart from gawk

Comment: I mean, what's the logic behind substituting `.+?` by `[^,]+`?

Comment: `[^,]+` stands for: any character BUT `,` repeated 1 or more time. I'm not quite sure what `.+?` means in `awk` speak - I believe this's somewhat perl-ish.

Comment: Well `.+?,` means the same as `[^,]+` in non-awk regex :). Thanks. As your solution is simpler, I am switching the accepted answer to you. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk` I believe.

```
echo "sentence_1,My \POS{tailor,noun} is \POS{rich,adj}." | 
awk '
{
  first=val=finalVal=""
  count=0
  while(match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+ \\POS{[^,]*/)){
    if(++count==1){
      first=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    }
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    sub(/\\POS{/,"",val)
    finalVal=(finalVal?finalVal OFS:"")val
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  print first finalVal
}'
```

OR try following, in case you have anything in line after `\POS{rich,adj}.` like `.` in this case then have it this way:

```
echo "sentence_1,My \POS{tailor,noun} is \POS{rich,adj}." | 
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+ \\POS{[^,]*/)){
    if(++count==1){
      first=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    }
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    sub(/\\POS{/,"",val)
    finalVal=(finalVal?finalVal OFS:"")val
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  sub(/.*}/,"")
  print first finalVal $0
}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
echo "sentence_1,My \POS{tailor,noun} is \POS{rich,adj}." |  ##Using echo to print value.
                                               ##Sending its output as input to awk program.
awk '                                          ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  first=val=finalVal=""                        ##Nullifying variables here.
  count=0                                      ##Setting count to 0 here.
  while(match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+ \\POS{[^,]*/)){    ##Using while loop to run match in it.
  ##Match has regex to match one or more alphabets space \POS{ till comma comes.
    if(++count==1){                            ##Checking condition if count is 1 then do following.
      first=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)              ##Creating first to have everything before matched this should have very first matches before value eg--> sentence_1,My
    }
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)              ##Creating val which is sub string of matched regex.
    sub(/\\POS{/,"",val)                       ##Using substitute \POS{ with NULL.
    finalVal=(finalVal?finalVal OFS:"")val     ##Creating finalVal to have all values in it.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)               ##Re-creating whole line to have only rest of the line in it, removing matched part.
  }
  print first finalVal                         ##Printing first and finalVal here.
}'
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ivallesp, Your welcome cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @ivallesp, I have added a 2nd solution also now, in case you have some leftover values in your line you could use 2nd one then, let me know in case of any queries(added detailed explanation also for codes).

Comment: Ok thanks! I guess you can leave the second solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `sed` solution using negated bracket expressions:

```sh
s='sentence_1,My \POS{tailor,noun} is \POS{rich,adj}.'
sed -E s'/\\POS\{([^,]+),[^}]*\}/\1/g' <<< "$s"

sentence_1,My tailor is rich.
```

**RegEx Explained:**

- `\\POS\{`: Match `\POS{`
- `([^,]+)`: Match 1 or more non-comma characters and capture in group #1
- `,`: Match a comma
- `[^}]*`: Match 0 or more non-`}` characters
- `\}`: Match a `}`
- `/\1`: Substitution is `\1` i.e. back-reference of capture group #1